# keeping users info

Tags: php, mysql

I can get a user to login but how do I carry their info over to other pages? I would like for `$thisUser` to hold the query for all the info for

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
```

Below is my code for logging them in.

```
    <?php

require_once 'includes\constants.php';

class Mysql{
    private $conn;

    function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('There was  a problem conecting to the database.');
    }

    function verify_username_and_pass($un, $pwd) {      
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";

        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)){
            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$un,$pwd);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
        }
    }
    }

}

    <?php

require 'classes\mysql.php';

class Membership{

    function validate_user($un,$pwd) {
        $mysql = New Mysql();
        $ensure_credentials = $mysql->verify_username_and_pass($un,md5($pwd));

        if($ensure_credentials) {
            $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
            header("location: index.php");
            } else return "Please enter a correct username and password";
    }

    function log_user_out() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['status']);

            if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) 
                setcookie(session_name(),'',time() - 10000 );
                session_destroy();
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Sessions and/or cookies seem perfect for this

Comment: -1 and no reason... thanks :D

Comment: @GlenMorse: Some people downvote when a question has been asked multiple times. To the right there is a "Related" section and there seem to be many questions that are very similar to yours. This is my guess as to why you have been downvoted. I agree that it would be nice if a downvote came with a small explanation so one can modify the question to make it better. I feel ya! [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) is an interesting discussion on forcing people to explain their downvotes.

Comment: @dudeonrock i can see that, one thing about the related list that i have an issue with is alot of the time its related but not with same code..  Though most of the time my questions are with delphi..something not to common. They should add the related to look at tags also..:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is stateless, that means that you can't save data between pageloads. However you can use something called a session with PHP that enables you to store data across calls to the server (pageloads).

It is really easy just call `session_start()` and then you start working with the global `$_SESSION` variable. Sessions are unique per visitor.

[the manual for sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

and a [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Comment: i belive i am using sessions or thought so. one of the fields is username.  if i try $_Session['username'] it does not return.

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling session_start()?

Comment: not sure.. but the $_Session['status'] is working so i thought sessions where started. Do i call this once or once per page?

Comment: Each page that needs to use it.

Comment: You must call session_start() before using session variables on every 'page' that gets loaded, note not every file. With that i mean you don't have to call session_start() in a included file if the file that includes it allready has called session_start().

Comment: ok great, so i need to add session start , but i think i may have strayed from my question. The data in the $query, to add that all to $_Session ?  as i dont really think doing $_Session['username'] = $query['username'] and then repeat for each field.

Comment: If I remember correctly you can save arrays to a session variable, but you can't save or it is a hassle to save objects to a session variable.

Comment: ok, so best to save usersID and just use the session to get users id and do query after i got the id on the new page.  :D thanks for help

Comment: Arrays work great with sessions, but objects need to be serialized to work... and a bug in PHP means that the returned value is no longer able to be unserialized. This would be brilliant if they ever fix it!

Comment: I would of accepted but i still cant get it to work. i understand the whole $_Session thing but with the code provided, i cant figure out how to add the ID field from db to $_Session['id'].  I know i would need to add it to the if($ensure_credentials) area but i am missing something on how to get the data from database and put it there using the code i have above. Ill continue to work on it but i feel iam missing something easy..

Answer (score 0):

I would hold the information in `$_SESSION` to keep it throughout the site. When the used logs in, add the information, after they pass the login, to the `$_SESSION` you need to keep.

Comment: You would need to set the start the `$_SESSION` with `session_start();` to start using `$_SESSION`. Each page that uses the `$_SESSION` will need the `session_start();` - or you can add it to a file that's included throughout the site.

@daniel-figueroa has some good links for getting started.

Answer (score -2):

The very simplest model you can create is with something like...

At the top of any script that invokes a session:

```
session_start();
```

And then to create name/value pairs in the session:

```
$_SESSION['blnLoggedIn'] = $blnLoggedIn;
```

Then to query or test the value stored:

```
echo $_SESSION['blnLoggedIn'];
```

This value can then be queried at the top of any 'secure' page, and in the event that the user is no longer logged in they can be redirected to a login page.

```
if (!$_SESSION['blnLoggedIn']) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/login');
}
    [...'secure' page content...]
}
```

The problem with sessions is that they only last for an arbitrary time period (about 24 minutes if I recall). With more work you can create a login model that uses `$_SESSION`, a cookie, and a database, to determine whether they should still be logged in after the session expires. There are various ways to do this, but the simplest is to store the username in a vanilla cookie. Upon session expiration, when a new page is hit, the cookie is used to query the database and determine whether they were logged in within a certain timeframe, say an hour. The time that they log in is recorded in the database for this, and other purposes.

For more detail, read the PHP manual on [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Pay close attention to the user-submitted comments; they're invaluable.

Comment: It's a reference manual. If you don't know what you're looking for, it's hard to know what to look up.

Comment: i am still kind of new to sessions, manual is huge, i find getting a little help here and playing around with it helps me learn.